# Array interpolation in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have two arrays :

```
array_x = [x1, x2, x3, x4... xn]
array_y = [y1, y2, y3, y4... yn]
```

I would like to have a function `f(array_x, array_y, value_x)` that returns the `value_y` associated to the `value_x` by interpolation into the arrays.

How to do that ?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are looking for. Do you want the value from `array_y` that is in the position corresponding to where `value_x` is in `array_x`?

Comment: @Noio: Say you have values [1,2,3] at times [10,20,30], the idea is to iterpolate the value at say time 24. There are lots of ways to do this. The simplest is just a piecewise linear interpolation, which is what `numpy.interp` uses.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that `numpy.interp` is exactly what you want.  e.g.:

```
numpy.interp(value_x,array_x,array_y)
```

Note that here `value_x` can be a scalar or another array-like value.  If it is an array-like value, you will be returned an array of corresponding interpolated values.

Comment: Hm... How to write this my own? Some people complain that they got no numpy, so I need this myself...

Comment: Linear interpolation is a pretty well known algorithm.  From there, it's just a matter of searching the array (could use bisection) for the elements that bound the value where you want to interpolate to -- With that said, for any real mathematical analysis, `numpy` seems to be the standard.  Is there a reason why those people can't install numpy?

Comment: When I make game, I wouldn't want to place a tester for numpy(if it is installed) and installer(if it is not). So...